# the windows 8.1 sdk is already referenced

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, windows-phone-8

I have created a simple HelloWorld app and deployed it to my Windows Phone.  It works as expected.

I am now trying to create an app, which uses SQL.  I have tried following the tutorial here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx, which involves adding the following references:

Imports System.Data.Linq;

```
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq;
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping;
```

None of the imports are recognised.  Therefore I have tried adding references i.e. right click on solution and select add/references.  However, it says: "the windows 8.1 sdk is already referenced".  Therefore I am unable to reference anything.

What am I doing wrong? I realize the code in the link is written in C#.  I have translated it into VB.NET.

Comment: Is this a silverlight phone app?  Sql Compact is only available in the silverlight project.  if you are using the windows RT phone projects use SQLite instead

Comment: @Ken Tucker, thanks. I am new to windows phone development. The project type is: Windows phone. How do I know if it is windows rt?

Comment: the template would say silverlight windows phone project if it was not a windows rt phone project.

Comment: @Ken Tucker, thanks.  However, step 1 of the following tutorial does not say create a Silverlight project: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx ?

Comment: @Ken Tucker, please see the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/ff402526(v=vs.105).aspx  Do I need to select: Windows Phone Silverlight and XNA application?